# Problema con los Puertos Seriales de VirtualBox

Tags: arduino

Estoy realizando un proyecto en arduino que es de mi escuela. Este proyecto fue pensado hacerlo en clase mediante un Rasperrry PI, pero dadas las circunstancias tenemos que hacerlo mediante arduino y una simulación con Raspbian OS.

Ya tengo programado todo el código principal en arduino, e incluso manda valores de forma serial, y de igual forma puede leerlos, ya que esta configurado para que si el usuario introduce ciertos caracteres realice ciertas actividades.

Mi problema son los puertos, estoy trabajando con KDE NEON y estoy intentando realizar la conexion de puertos mediante VirtualBox pero no me funciona.
Asi es como tenngo el puerto en Arduino en mi Sistema Linux Normal.
[image: Puerto Arduino]

Es el /dev/tty/USB0. Pero cuando intento realizar las pruebas ya en el otro Sistema Linux, me pierdo en tema de puertos, ya que no me ha funcionado, o no se que configuración deba de realizar. Asi es como tengo configurado los puertos en VirtualBox:
[image: VirtualBox Puertos]

Comment: puedes indicar cual es el SO anfitrión donde esta corriendo virtual box y que SO tienes emulando. Me pierdo un poco en tu explicación.

Comment: Es Raspbian, que es el que viene con el Raspberry..Corre bajo Debian.

Comment: y en tu sistema anfitrión que puerto es el que tienes asignado al COM? el /dev/ttyUSB0 ?

Comment: creo que lo otro que puedes hacer, es no compartir el puerto serie, si no el dispositivo USB, con eso pasas el dispositivo completo al SO emulado.

Comment: Al parecer ya lo solucione, el número de puerto puse COM2 y ya en código de Python para que detectará el dispositivo puse /dev/ttyS1 que al parecer es su equivalente en Linux. Finalmente en ruta dirección puse /dev/ttyUSB0, que anteriormente lo había intentado poner, pero no me dejaba. Al parecer era por que en ese momento tenia el IDE del arduino con el monitor serial abierto y detectaba el BUS como ocupado. Pero ya en este momento, me esta leyendo los datos de manera correcta.

Comment: Puedes autoresponderte la pregunta, y dejar mas detalles, con el fin de que le pueda ayudar a otra persona.